# How do I pass quotes within SSH command?

Tags: python, windows, ssh, cmd, openssh

I am trying to run a remote script in windows over ssh, and I cannot figure out how to handle the quotes. (Both host and client are windows machines.) This is the statement which works fine on the host machine:

```
C:\> python "C:\folder path\file.py"
```

I have looked seemingly everywhere, and tried seemingly everything, but I cannot get this to work:

```
C:\> ssh user@ipaddress "python ""C:\folder path\file.py"""
python: can't open file 'C:\folder': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have tried using double quotes, I have tried single quotes, I have tried '\' as an escape character, I have tried '^', and nothing seems to pass the string correctly. Any help?!

EDIT:
A user suggested I use '-v' with ssh to track the path. Doing that, it looks like the double quotes actually do what I expect, but somehow the host machine misinterprets the command, and objects to the space. Not sure why...

To be clear, using this:

```
C:\> ssh -v user@ipaddress "python ""C:\folder path\file.py"""
```

I see this in the results:

```
debug1: Sending command: python "C:\folder path\file.py"
python: can't open file 'C:\folder': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

AGAIN, to be more clear, this command works PERFECTLY when I am phsyically at the host machine:

```
C:\> python "C:\folder path\file.py"
```

So, I am unclear why/where this is getting screwed up. Thanks for any help, you all have helped immensely thus far. Also, I am using OpenSSH. Someone mentioned cygwin, which I am not familiar with. I am not using that, unless it is implicitly used by OpenSSH.

***ALSO, I added python, because python seems to be the one throwing the error.*** I.e. - 'python: can't open file 'C:\folder': [Errno 2] No such file or directory', so I am unsure if there is some python nuance I need to be wary of.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Python. Questions about general-purpose software like ssh are best asked on [su].

Comment: `ssh user@ipaddress "python 'C:\folder path\file.py'"` ... just use singlequotes

Comment: Doesn't work... Same error.

Comment: Does the file exists on the client machine at that location? 
if so try escaping the quotes with \  ssh user@ipaddress "python \'C:\folder path\file.py \' "

Comment: Yes. As mentioned, the statement works on the host machine, so the path and the file exist in that location. And escaping the single quotes does not work. I am getting the same error.

Comment: `ssh <IP> "python '/home/user/bad dir/pal.py'"` works on Ubuntu - it runs the script. You could try directly escaping the space.

Comment: @Rob I posted it on Super User, so apologies. I get your point, but from my experience, that place seems to be a ghost town when I ask stuff like this.

Comment: This is windows. Regrettably, unix style stuff doesn't really help.

Comment: One thing you may want to try: `ssh -v <whatever>` will print debug information, including the exact command it is sending: `debug1: Sending command: python '/home/user/bad dir/pal.py'` If you can copy/paste that into the remote shell and have it work, then *shrug*

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful. It showed me what was being sent, and it looks like double quotes are sending the correct command (python "C:\folder path\file.py"), but the command is failing, not liking the space, something it does not object to locally. Doesn't seem to make sense....

Comment: I'd append that to your SuperUser post -> the issue is with whatever ssh server you're using cygwin perhaps?

Comment: @TemporalWolf: cygwin make a translation of Windows paths. The OP should try forward slashes instead of back slashes (because Python can understand that). Try: `ssh user@ipaddress "python 'C:/folder path/file.py'"`

Comment: Tried forward slashes. Didn't work. Not familiar with cygwin, but definitely not using it.